# In Mandrill's API, is there any way to know the size limits of JSON attributes in their Responses?

Tags: mandrill

I'm looking at the Mandrill API documentation e.g. https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.JSON.html#method=info. In the JSON response there may be seomthing like the following

```
    {
        "ts": 1365190001,
        "url": "http://www.example.com",
        "ip": "55.55.55.55",
        "location": "Georgia, US",
        "ua": "Linux/Ubuntu/Chrome/Chrome 28.0.1500.53"
    }
```

Is there are way to know how large the String's may be for these attributes? i.e. how many characters might be returned for "ua" or "url" etc... I'm asking as I need to capture and store some of this data in Oracle, but I don't want to LOB everything!

Comment: Are you using a programming language? or something?

Comment: Good point :), I'm working with the Java wrapper for Mandrill https://github.com/cribbstechnologies/Java-Mandrill-Wrapper. But Mandrill has many wrappers I guess...

Comment: I do not know a lot of java, but I think you can parse the json, and then access to the "url" key and see the length, hope this helps you http://answers.oreilly.com/topic/257-how-to-parse-json-in-java/